# what is function of () in str(getattr(platfrom,'node')()) for python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

Python is 2.7.11, and terminal is powershell.

When running below:

```
>>> import platform

>>> str(getattr(platform,'node')())

'CN00054688'

>>> str(getattr(platform,'node'))

'<function node at 0x0000000002E74908>'
```

() inside str() seems has different output.

Why?

Comment: Is this something you actually saw somewhere? It's not something that makes sense to write; you'd just do `platform.node()`.

Comment: >>> str(getattr(platform,'node'))
'<function node at 0x0000000002E74908>'  it is like this.

Comment: what is the function for the second () in str(()()) when the first () is callable object?

Comment: Seems understand some:str(getattr(platform,'node')) )==str(platfrom.node)   and str(getattr(platfrom,'node'())==str(platfrom.node())   so different output.

Comment: It calls the callable, of course.

Comment: If want to finish below print output according to predefined list.

>>import platform

>>test = ['node','uname','version']

>>for name in test:
>>>>    print platform.'%s'(),name

How to write it?

How to implement above function?